# Implementing simple shader program and render

Tags: opengl

I am trying to implement a simple shader program and render a set of vertices and a strange error occur:

[image]

Is this something regarding the depth buffer? I think I had a similar problem before.

Inside my draw method:

```
// Parameters: GLdouble* vertices, int num_vertices;
Gluint vboId;
glGenBuffers(1,&vboId);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vboId);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLdouble) * num_vertices * 3, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vboId);
glVertexPointer(3,GL_DOUBLE,0,NULL);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glUseProgram(shaderProgramId);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,num_vertices);



// Shader program

// Vertex
void main(void) {
gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}

// Fragment
void main(void) {
gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

Comment: Your shader looks fine. It seems your vertex data is corrupt. Do you have only triangles in the VBO? Are there any dummy vertices? Obviously, the wrong vertices are connected with a face.

Comment: Ok! You are probably right, my vertices:

GLdouble* vertices = new GLdouble[mesh->nv];
int num_vertices = mesh->nv;

for(int i = 0; i < mesh->nv; i++){
    vertices[i*3] = mesh->vertices[i].x;
    vertices[i*3+1] = mesh->vertices[i].y;
    vertices[i*3+2] = mesh->vertices[i].z;
}

// Sorry, dont know how to edit this nice.

Comment: Do you have any indices? It seems as if you're drawing triangles from vertex data only, yet your vertex array seems to rely on indices to form triangles.

Comment: @Bart I think I do have, but I lack understanding. My mesh have a set of triangles and a variable nt ( num of triangles). And It have a set of vertices with a variable nv ( num of vertices ). How would I build a correct array to use with glDrawArrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was drawing without indice and the model needed indices. As @Bart said in comments.

To fix this issue, I call:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,num_indices * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);
```

instead of:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,num_vertices);
```

Comment: That had to be it. :) You might want to include what you did to modify your code and show us how you got it to work. Then you'll have a nice and complete answer.